# Video limit about wordpress

Tags: uploads, limit

Good morning, 
actually i'm going to start with a new entrepreneur project and I'm thinking about build the website in Wordpress but I'll need to upload many GB of video everyday. There's some limit about the upload or the quality of the video?
Will I be able to upload also from a FTP like Filezilla?

Thanks

Comment: By limit your mean, maximum upload size in wordpress?

Comment: Yeah, what if I have to upload very big sized video? There's a limit?

Answer (score 0):

there is no limit to how much video you can upload, apart from disk space on the server. There is also a limit on how big each file can be according to your PHP configuration, but on on the combined size of all the videos.

Your challenges in this project will be preparing the videos for online viewing (I'd go for mp4-files using h.264 and aac audio).

If you expect huge traffic, I'd consider using Cloudfront for serving the videos.

Also, your server should not be busy with converting and preparing these videos. Perhaps you should consider converting them before you upload them.

Alternatively, you need to look into scaling that part of your site either by using a third party transcoding service or rolling your own.

I'm sure you can find a plugin that handles file uploads via FTP, or makes it possible to download files FROM your FTP server TO your WordPress installation.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, If you upload your file via `filezila` in `upload folder` of wordpress then those files won't be visible in `media` (dashboard -> media) becuase by uploading via filezila it won't get any entry in database, and if you will try to select file from `dashboard -> page` by clicking on `Add media` then you won't see your file since you uploaded it via `ftp`. But you can still add that file by defining path manually. For e.g. If an image is uploaded in upload folder then it can't be add via `Add media`, so you have to use img tag to show it like

```
<img src="Enter Path Manually">
```

This is the drawback of uploading via FTP that you have to enter path manually unlike `Add media` in which path get entered auto by wordpress on one click.And also you can't set featured/Thumbnail image if image uploaded via FTP.

AND if upload size is issue (default 2 mb) then that  issue can be resolved by increasing Maximum upload size. To resolve this issue you can either

1. Contact your hosting and ask to increase max upload size for you
2. Or do it yourself by editing `php.ini` file.

This article will guide you about editing `php.ini` file to increase upload size. http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-increase-the-maximum-file-upload-size-in-wordpress/  You can find many useful article regarding this by searching on google.